# PHP handle a checklist with a random amount of items

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a HTML Table which is used as a checklist. There are multiple checklists and user can create their own checklist and items as well. This checklist have a random amount of rows.

```
$table .= "<tr style='cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid black;' onclick='selectVal(this)'>
                          <td style='border: 1px solid transparent; width: 5%;' class='cbTrue'><input type='hidden' value='".$srcarr['id']."' name='item_id' /><input type='checkbox' name='".$srcarr['id']."_True' /></td>
                          <td style='border: 1px solid transparent; width: 30%;'>".$srcarr['item']."</td>
                          <td style='border: 1px solid transparent; width: 30%;'><input type='hidden' class='ckTimeStamp' /></td>
                     </tr>";
```

`$srcarr` is my array which comes from a MySQLI query and contains the information of the ID of an Item or the Name oft an Item.

My problem is: I want to save the items with the information if they have been checked and at which time in a MySQL Database. But I have no idea how to know after the form have been posted to PHP how I can separate the information about the single items. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you have some rows to add and you need to create a unique name for each input.

Try this:

```
<input type='hidden' value='".$srcarr['id']."' name='item_id[".$srcarr['id']."]' /><input type='checkbox' name='".$srcarr['id']."_True' />
```

Then in the form processing, loop through `$_POST['item_id']` and from keys of the array check if is set `$_POST[$key . '_TRUE']`

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant ^-^Sorry, its late here and my brain is allready sleeping, i guess^^ Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank you sir! Your way worked very well! Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the exact time when user click the checkbox not the moment when they submit the pages?

If it is the exact moment they check your checkbox you could use javascript to assign the time value on hidden input by adding it on event change at checkbox element.

on jquery it will be like:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="checkbox-name"]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        var now = new Date;
        $('input. ckTimeStamp').val(now.getTime);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that i have like 20 different items in this checklist. Now I want to send the checklist with a HTML Form to PHP. PHP should read every row of the table and get the value of all inputs of this table and save it in a MySQL Database. The problem is that this e.g. 20 different items can be totally different. And i dont know how to find out, which inputvalue belongs to which item ID^^

Answer (score 0):

See [Processing HTML checkbox forms with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813386/processing-html-checkbox-forms-with-php) for code example.

What you need is to have a list of checkbox with the same name like `custom_checkboxes[]` and store `$srcarr['id']` as a value. In PHP, when you receive the data as an array, only those `$srcarr['id']` that was checked will be included inside the array.

Comment: @JonasLöffel start by naming your checkboxes with the same name (but with [] in the end) PHP will see it as an array of checked IDs (do a var_dump on the PHP side to see it working)